# End of File command doesn't seem to do anything?

Tags: c++, encryption, eof

I'm new to programming so I am -as anyone would expect- not very experienced in understanding what's wrong.

The following is a code I wrote for encrypting the input that the user gives:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void encrypt (char text[]) { //SHIFT CYPHER ENCRYPTION

 int i, j, l = 0;

 char *a[26], c;

 char  p[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'} ; // Encrypted character array

 char character[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}; //Match character array


 for (i=0; i<26; i++) {
  a[i] = &p[i];         // Assign pointer array to char array
 }

 for (i=0; i<26; i++)
  cin >> *a[i];         // Get new values of characters

 c = '\0';
 while (c != EOF) {  //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS

  c = getchar();
  text[l] = c;  // Reads text input from user
  l++;

  for (i=0; i<26; i++) {

    if (text[l] == character[i]) text[l] = p[i];  // Encrypts text
    else continue; }

  }

  for (j=0; j<=l; j++)
    cout << text[l];  // Prints encrypted text

}

int main() {

  char text[1000];

  encrypt (text);       // Is this the correct way to call the encrypt procedure?

  return(0);

}
```

When I complie this and run it I give 26 different random characters off of the alphabet like the following:

```
poiuytrewqasdfghjklmnbvcxz
```

Then the input must be given by the user **and the program must print the encrypted message**.

However, when I'm done giving the input, `getchar()` will have to read the EOF value, which is Crtl-Z for windows and Ctrl-D for Unix OS.

I'm working on a mac OS with parallel Windows OS and the editor is on the Windows OS. I have tried both `Crtl-Z` and `Ctrl-D` and neither works after hitting `ENTER`.

For example the input is given like this:

```
what a beautiful sunny day for a walk, don't you think? <ENTER>
<CTRL-Z or CTRL-D> <ENTER>
```

**The program is still waiting for input after this and i dont really have any idea as to why.**

I also wanted to know if, in the `int main()` function, the argument `encrypt (text)` is the correct way to actually use the `void` procedure.

Thanks in advance!

***P.S:** I know this is probably not the best way to encrypt a given input but since im new to programming this was the forst thing that came to mind, so although I'm open to better ideas, I don't know if i will understand them fully.*

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't assign the result to any variable,`getchar` still reads a char and throw it away.

Next time you call `getchar`,it reads the next char.

Look at:

```
while (getchar() != EOF) {  //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
  text[l] = getchar();
```

Half of the input is only encrypted,and the other half is only compared to `EOF`

Change to:

```
char c='\0';
while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) {  //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
  text[l] = c;
```

so that all input is compared and encrypted.

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback! I'm not sure i understand though. Why do i have to write it like that? Doesn't getchar() get characters and assign them to the l-1_th position on the array, until it gets to the EOF?

Comment: Suppose the input is 'ab'.When program comes to `while (getchar() != EOF)`,`getchar` read the char `a` and compare it to EOF. Then the program comes to `text[l] = getchar(); `,now `getchar` is called again.This time it read 'b' and assign it to `text[l]`.

Comment: Also how do you put lines of code in your comment?

Comment: Thanks a lot i get it, I changed it

Comment: @808kalli:Use `\`` to quote your code. And `c=getchar(); while(c!=EOF) text[ l ] = c ;`is not right because `getchar` is outside `while` statement,it will only be called once.

Comment: Yeah thanks i realised that after answering to the comment.